# Does electron current flow through inside a battery when connected to an electrical load?

Tags: electrostatics, batteries

Many popular science sites display and describe that current flows through and inside a battery when connected into an electrical circuit.

But what then prevents current flowing inside the battery between its two terminals + and - when the battery is not connected to a circuit (i.e. open circuit)?

I have read in manufacturer specifications that a battery has practically zero leakage current between its terminals and a dielectric resistance of many MOhms.

How is it possible all the electrical circuit current flowing through the battery and in the same time  there is no electron current possible between the two terminals of the battery?

I am confused?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell

Answer (score 4):

The current flowing in the battery when the terminals are connected to a load is an ion current, this resolves the contradiction of being able to conduct current but not electrons. The electrode on the negative terminal of the battery is oxidized and dissolves as it gives off electrons, and ions are created and go into solution in the electrolyte and on the other electrode a different ion takes on the electrons and gets deposited on the electrode (a reduction reaction). The redox reactions at the electrodes is what provides the energy the battery gives off.

To keep the electrolyte net neutral a (net) ion current must flow. How this is going on depends on cell design (e.g. the negatively charged ions may flow from one side of a semi-permeable membrane to the other, while the positively charged ion concentrations on both sides of the membrane change). There are also cell designs that don't need a membrane, e.g. the [lead battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_battery).

When the terminals are not connected to a load, the electrolyte and the electrodes are in equilibrium between the electrochemical potentials of the electrodes and the voltage on the electrodes. So no ion-current is flowing (as the reaction rates of reduction and oxidation at each electrode are equal at the constant voltage that is kept between them). The electrolyte solution and the case of the battery do not conduct electrons well, so the battery only discharges slowly on its own.

A detailed description of the processes involved can be found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell.

(Of course, the electrolyte may indirectly conduct electrons due to ion-conduction mechanisms, e.g. a watery solution will undergo electrolysis, this is a real loss mechanism in some battery designs – e.g. leaky alkaline batteries are due to hydrogen production: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Leaks.)

Comment: (+1) As a chemist, I vote for this answer, though the negative electrode (the anode) oxidizes, not simply dissolves.

Comment: I was somehow confused as I recently viewed this video: https://youtu.be/DE3fazjYV-o&t=5m50s  According to your answer, this video is wrong?

Comment: @StefanH The final answer to this question is, that there is no electron current flowing through the battery when it is discharging through an electric load circuit. There is only charge displacement via the connected circuit from the negative plate  of the battery to the positive plate until the two potentials are equalized and voltage across the battery therefore nullified. All other explanations seen on youtube saying otherwise are only effective explanations which nothing have to do with reality.

Comment: @EdV I had the word redox-reaction in my first draft, and then simplified things – but you are absolutely right, I should edit the answer to make that point clearer.

Comment: Actually this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXNKkcB0pI4 describes in detail what happens in an typical alkaline battery which I believe is what here is referred to. There is no even an ion direct current flowing from the anode to the cathode. Both plates interact separately with the electrolyte solution and the electrolyte solution then adds electrons to the (-) terminal plate of the battery. The barrier I've described is real and prevents electron current directly flowing from one terminal plate to the other.

Comment: There is an ion current, there can be a net ion current even if different ions go into the solution on one side than are deposited on the other side (actually a different redox state must be deposited, otherwise there would be no energy). ...

Comment: The barrier has the same function as described in the Wikipedia article on the Galvanic cell (where you use a salt bridge or porous membrane) – to prevent plating of the less noble electrode. The barrier is not for electrons, it is to let only certain ions pass. If there were no ion current, charge would accumulate, which would mean that the external voltage of the battery would drop to zero.

Comment: It follows from basic principles that charge can't accumulate in a battery while the battery keeps an opposite voltage between its terminals. So there *must* be an ion current. The barrier does also not prevent charging, it just prevents mixing of the ions in the two half cells (which is not necessary, e.g. in the case of lead batteries). Re-charging is typically possible to some degree for non-rechargable batteries, it's just not safe (e.g. due to gas production) and they don't reach their original capacity.

Comment: Regarding the barriers: In designs with an semi-permeable membranes/salt bridges typically a third ion species, or only one of the ion species involved is transported across the barrier.) The point is that neutrality must be kept (up to the few electrons that accumulate against the capacitance to reach the equilbrium voltage).

Comment: And the barrier is typically not necessary for the basic function of the cell, but for continued operation. (E.g. in the copper-zinc cell the copper ions would plate the zinc, and thereby stop the redox-reaction of the zinc, making the battery non-operational quickly).

Comment: @SebastianRiese The barrier or else called separator is absolutely necessary for the operation of the battery as a voltage source otherwise the battery would be short circuit it due electron flow and not able to create and maintain a potential difference through the ongoing electrochemical reaction process. Please see my updated answer with the video and note description at the end of the answer.

Comment: No problem about redox stuff! We get quite a few galvanic (voltaic) cell questions over at chem SE. The salt bridge, and why cations move toward the cathode, etc., vexes more people than I ever would have guessed, even after decades of chemistry teaching.